# 301 redirection in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Scrapy project. I scrape items of a page (I have 10 000 URLS in total). When there is an item, it works. The problem is when there isn't any item.

I have a 301 redirection (`DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.reezocar.com/search/Alfa+Romeo+166+3.0+V6.html?energy=petrol&gearbox=manual&yearMin=1999&yearMax=2003&doors=45&withPicture=off&size=120> from <GET https://reezocar.com/search/Alfa+Romeo+166+3.0+V6.html?energy=petrol&gearbox=manual&yearMin=1999&yearMax=2003&doors=45&withPicture=off&size=120>`)

I guess the problem comes from the fact that there is no item but I have another spider for another website that is based on the same code that works well when there is no item on the page.

The spider code:

```
class AnnonceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'rzc_results'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data_file = pkgutil.get_data(
            "rzc_spider", "json/input/complete_rzc_scrape_rectif.json")
        self.data = json.loads(data_file)

    def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.data:
            request = scrapy.Request(item['rzc_url'], callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):

        item = response.meta['item']
        item['results'] = []

        #item["car_number"] = []
        item["car_number"] = response.css(
            "h2.subTitle_1guol7j::text").extract_first()
        #if len(item["car_number"]) == 0:
        #        item["car_number"] = None

        for caritem in response.css("div.adCardOuter_d2sn17 > div[itemprop='item']"):
            data = AnnonceItem()
            #model
            data["model"] = []
            data["model"] = caritem.css("h2.title_16j3u81 > div::text").extract_first()
            if len(data["model"]) == 0:
                data["model"] = None
            #price
            data["price_str"] = []
            data["price_str"] = caritem.css(
                "div.price_1anxiw > span::text").extract_first()
            if len(data["price_str"]) == 0:
                data["price_str"] = None

            item['results'].append(data)

        yield item

        next_page = response.css(
            'a.link_huvdae-o_O-linkPrevNext_1v3fox8::attr(href)').extract_first() 
        if next_page is not None:
            url_pagination = 'https://www.reezocar.com' + next_page

            meta = {'item': response.meta['item']}
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url_pagination, callback=self.parse, meta=meta)
```

Comment: A 301 redirect isn't necessarily a problem. What is the exact issue other than being redirected?

Comment: Yeah, I changed my mind. The problem is that certain urls are not scraped and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Include these options in the request.

`yield Request('url',
               meta = {
                      'dont_redirect': True,
                      'handle_httpstatus_list': [301,302]
                  },
                  callback= self.func)`

Also, try to set `dont_redirect` flag in the settings file to affect the change globally.